# "Cannot run program error=2" on Linux

Tags: java, linux, io

I'm having an app running in Tomcat 7.0.32 on Linux server. The app runs program in a file.
The problem is that all of a sudden I got

```
"Cannot run program "./bLogin.sh" error=2, No such file or directory"
```

Of course, I didn't erase the file. After a while, the issue stopped (again, without intervention) and the app runs fine.
What can cause it? the only thing that I can think of is out of space issue that occuered during the period.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this command

```
unset CATALINA_HOME
```

This command will unset the environmental variable CATALINA_HOME.

Comment: Can you explain why setting it would cause random "not found" issue?

Comment: May be version cause the issue, have you tried to run your program again.

Comment: It runs on automated interval. It was down for ~2 days and came back to life without me touching the code/config

Comment: Ok, then wait for anyone else for this issue, I don't think I got the problem right way. Sorry to take your time.